OAuth error configuring Zapier with Google My Business API
I have an approved project in Google Cloud and I'm trying to create an integration connecting my Google My Business account with zapier on developer.zapier.com. I keep getting an error though - "Request Failed. You need to choose a connected account or send something in the authData property."
I made sure I pasted the correct client ID and secret ID. I generated and pasted Zapier's OAuth Redirect UR into my projects. I added correct scopes to manage my profiles -> Google My Business API.../auth/business.manage.
My configuration is as follows:

I copied and added the url to my project in Google Cloud.

I checked whether I pasted correct data MULTIPLE times

I filled authorization URL with what I found in my clienc_secret.json file and left url params as they were

I filled the access token with what I found on the Internet, but I keep getting the same mistake:

Is there a mistake in the setup here, or is it more probable that I messed something up the project in Google Cloud?
